# Equivalent of PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer to PropertyOverrideConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer could look up values for place holders from property sources. Is there an equivalent to that for PropertyOverrideConfigurer which uses the property source to override the property definition?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer>
        <property name="location" value="file:${your_property_from_PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer}/override.properties"/>
        <property name="localOverride" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks androberz. But, what I was looking for is a way to make PropertyOverrideConfigurer to look at the PropertySources in the Environment rather than for a property file location, for loading the properties.

Comment: Wrom what I can see at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12853 this functionality not working at 4.1.6 and think it could work in the snapshot rel 4.2.0